# Can I minimise another app started from an Air App via NativeProcess?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have developed a simple air app to automate a system. The first thing the app does is to launch two other programs (.exe on windows) via NativeProcess. This is all working fine but I can't see any way of minimising those programs.

Is this possible via NativeProcess or some other workaround?

Comment: I haven't try but [/min option](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000932.htm) doesn't solve this issue?

Comment: thanks for the idea. Unfortunately I need the two other programs to run normally at first, for the user to configure their settings, and then I need to minimise them...

Comment: AFAIK there's no universal way to do this, but if those programs support it, you could send a socket request to ask them to minimize.  I have to ask, though - how will your AIR app know when to minimize the other windows?  Why can't you rely on the user to close/minimize the other programs when they're done configuring them?